# How to left align my horizontal rule in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have:

```
---
output: pdf_document
---


Article

----------
```

Very simple markdown file. RStudio generates the following for the markdown:

[image]

Q: How to move (left-align) the line to below the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not RStudio, but `pandoc` generating that PDF from your markdown file, which transforms `---` to `\begin{center}\rule{0.5\linewidth}{\linethickness}\end{center}` when using the LaTeX renderer. If you do not like this default, you might want to override that, or to keep it simple: use LaTeX instead of markdown for that horizontal line, eg remove the centering.